# Can I query an SO tag?

Tags: support, tags, data-explorer

I want to study the trends of technology, say C++ or C, and want to see how often people post a question with related tags. Can this be done? Is the data publicly accessible? If yes, where? I'd also appreciate if someone can link to API docs of similar querying examples.

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/, your local treasure trove of Stack Overflow data + sample queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://data.stackexchange.com would be a good start. If you are any good with SQL, definitely a first stop.

It contains a weekly import of data from across the Stack Exchange network with a SQL interface to query it.

If you don't need super recent data, you can get the [data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) which hosted on archive.org - it contains data for all sites.